# Django: Add space after a comma in a string using javascript in a template

Tags: javascript, django

In an html template I get a variable's value from a select drop down list like

```
one or more,two
```

In need to add an extra space after the comma and I need my string to be

```
one or more, two
```

My current javascript is:

```
 $('#id_diag-diagnosis_option').change(function () {
     var value = $(this).val()
     alert(value)
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: do you control the value in the select dropdown?

Comment: @dm03514 What do you mean by "control"?

Comment: Do you have control of the HTML the template? If so add the space there and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value.replace(/\s/g, '').split(",").join(", ")
```

should work for all cases (anything other than one space after comma)

Comment: Still nothing! :( `alert(value.split(",").join(", "))` does nothing.

Comment: Works for me. Please give more detail of your problem.

Comment: @Xotic750 How do you do it? `var value = $(this).val()
     alert(value.split(",").join(", "))` does nothing.

Comment: added an even more general solution

Comment: @zxzak If I initiate value like `value = "one,two"` this is working. If I get the value from the html div id, it does not work.

Comment: what is the value of "value" after you assign $(this).val() to it , what is printed inside the alert box ?

Comment: I would suggest that you create a working example for us to look at, HTML and javascript  then we may be able to see what you are doing wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: OK, I found the solution. I have to convert `$(this).val()` to string, using `var value = String($(this).val())`

Answer (score 1):

```
var after = before.replace(",", ", ");
```

Should work (Before being the string before the change, and after being after)

Comment: Can you get a jsfiddle of what you've got already please, it's difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: Works for me. Please give more detail of your problem.

Comment: @Xotic750 If I initiate value like `value = "one,two"` this is working. If I get the value from the html div id, it does not work.